# Java thread doesn't stop/interrupt

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to terminate a thread but it doesn't interrupt or stop. All of this are part of controller of a software called Webots. I use this to simulate a multi robot system. In the controller of each robot, I start a thread which receive messages through robots receivers. This thread must start at first, and terminate when simulation ends.

The run method for this thread look like this:

```
public void run() {
    while (true)
    {
        String M = recieveMessage();
        char[] chars = M.toCharArray();
        if(chars[0]==robotName||chars[0]=='0')
            messages.add(M);                                                
     }
}
```

In the main controller I have code that look like this:

```
MessageThread MT = new MessageThread(messages, receiver,getName());
MT.start();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    try
    {
         Thread.sleep(25);  } catch (InterruptedException e) {      e.printStackTrace();    }
    System.out.println(messages.get(messages.size()-1));                
 }
 MT.interrupt();//MT = null;
 System.out.println(MT.interrupted());
```

It's not important what I do in my main controller, so don't judge it. For example, messages is an ArrayList. It's like a buffer which MT put messages in and the main thread reads from. I use it because the receiver and emitter are not synchronized.

If I call interrupt() or MT = null but interrupted() it returns false and MT continues to run. Is there anything wrong in my code?

I read some topics like:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

[How do you kill a Thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java)

[interrupt() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627719/interrupt-doesnt-work)

[Java: How interrupt/stop a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599202/java-how-interrupt-stop-a-thread)

and so on but I couldn't find any useful answer.

### Edit

Thanks everyone, I've made changes to my code. I added this to the MessageThread class:

```
private volatile boolean isRunning = true;
```

Then I used `while(isRunning)` instead of `while(true)` and I added

```
public void kill()
{
    isRunning = false;
}
```

and called `MT.kill()` instead of `MT.interrupt()`.

It worked but I couldn't find out what's wrong with interrupt(). I read the link which @ExtremeCoders recommended. However, I'm still confused. It says *"a thread must support its own interruption".* So do I have to overwrite the interrupt() method? I can't call interrupt to terminate a thread?

Thanks again.

Comment: What do you think `interrupt` does? And what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to stop MT thread when my main controller finises.

Comment: `interrupt` does not work the way you think. You have to check `interrupted` flag in your loop and break accordingly. See ***[this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)*** link

Comment: So how can I stop MT thread?
I know Thread.stop() has some problems. In java docs, they stop thread by setting it to null. I tried it but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: @Taher Instead of a `while(true)` loop use `while(!Thread.interrupted())`

Comment: @SamiKorhonen Sorry, i didn't get it.

Answer (score 5):

Interrupting a thread just sets a flag on the thread. If the thread never checks the flag, it won't respond. By creating your own `boolean` member, you've duplicated that functionality unnecessarily.

Here's the general pattern for what you are trying to do:

```
@Override
public void run() {
  while(!Thread.interrupted() {
    /* Do something. */
  }
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

This will allow you to call `MT.interrupt()` as you expected. It's better than creating your own flag and custom method to set it: you can use your `Runnable` task with high-level tools like `ExecutorService` and cancellation will work because you used the standard API; same is true for interruption of an entire `ThreadGroup`.

Calling `Thread.interrupted()` clears the interruption status of a thread; we set it by calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`, the status is set again so that callers of `run()` can detect the interrupted state. This might not always be desirable however.

Comment: Thanks, as @ExtremeCoders suggested, I used while(!Thread.interrupted()) but MT Thread didn't stop!!! So I decide to define my own flag.

Comment: @Taher Did you use that together with a call to `MT.interrupt()`? Because it will definitely work; if it didn't, you did something wrong.

Comment: Yes, I did and I surprised why MT is still running. I changed my while loop with while(!Thread.interrupted()) and I added hread.currentThread().interrupt(); after while and I called MT.interrupt() in main thread.